# Changing endpoint but want to keep old endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

We have some endpoints that we want to change but still want to keep using old ones for some time.

Example: Current Endpoint: /download -> New Endpoint: /document/download. We want to use both.

The Endpoints are defined in a class.
Current:

```
class Endpoints {
  public static final DOCUMENT_HOME = "/home";
  public static final DOWNLOAD = "/download";
}

@RequestMapping(Endpoints.DOCUMENT_HOME)
class DocumentController {
  @GetMapping(value = Endpoints.DOWNLOAD)
  public void download();
}
```

New:

```
class Endpoints {
  public static final DOCUMENT_HOME = "/home/document";
  public static final DOWNLOAD = "/download";
}

@RequestMapping(Endpoints.DOCUMENT_HOME)
class DocumentController {
  @GetMapping(value = Endpoints.DOWNLOAD)
  public void download();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can't you just add another GET request?

Comment: We are doing it to make things standard. There is another endpoint, let's say /video/download. So there is a /download in both cases. Since document one is written earlier, it was written with /download. Now there is /video/download, so we want to make it /document/download. This is just an example, in actuality, there are many endpoints in /document and in /video, we want /document to be added in all the document endpoints, but do not want the old endpoints to stop working. Is there anything we can do to redirect old endpoints to new ones in some config file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use both endpoints then write code like this.

```
class Endpoints {
  public static final DOCUMENT_HOME = "/home";
  public static final DOWNLOAD = "/download";
  public static final DOCUMENT = “/document”;
}

@RequestMapping(Endpoints.DOCUMENT_HOME)
class DocumentController {
  @GetMapping(value = Endpoints.DOWNLOAD)
  public void downloadV1();

   @GetMapping(value = Endpoints.DOCUMENT + Endpoints.DOWNLOAD)
  public void downloadV2();

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how meaningful your request is, but you can use it by doing something like this.

```
@GetMapping({"/public/v1/oldEndPoint/{id}", "/private/v1/newEndPoint/{id}"})
```